# Create an object from file - java

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce, gson

I have a problem , i should pass to mapper (map reduce of hadoop) an object, so i try to put the object in a json like that:

```java
Object2ObjectOpenHashMap<OpenBitSet, CombinationHelper> level1 = ...;
String level1path="pathFile.txt";

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String JsonLevel1 = gson.toJson(level1);

BufferedWriter writerContainTuples = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(level1path));
writerContainTuples.write(JsonLevel1);
writerContainTuples.close();
```

In mapper i usually bring the object from file in that way:

```java
public void map(Object ke, Text val, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    
    level1 = new Gson().fromJson(val.toString(), new TypeToken<Object2ObjectOpenHashMap<OpenBitSet, CombinationHelper>>(){}.getType());
        ...       
    }
}
```

but when i run the programm it give me that error:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3
```

So I don't know how I should pass my object if in this way java give me this error. I've tried with the serializable, but in mapper phase it give me almost the same error.

Comment: Looks like the value passed to `fromJson` is not JSON. Print `val.toString()` you will know

Comment: @SunilDabburi this is the syso of val.toString()




{"org.apache.lucene.util.OpenBitSet@cf13db96":{"rhsCandidates":{"bits":[62],"wlen":1},"valid":true,"partition":{"error":11175.0,"elementCount":150,"strippedPartition":[somethings],"maxCardinality":149.0}}}
]

Comment: Interesting. Can you confirm if there is a `”` at the start of JSON? The one that you shared looks valid

Comment: There is `]` at the end which shouldn’t be unless you are not sharing complete output

Comment: MapReduce defaults to breaking each line of the file apart... Why not use Spark, which has a JSON parser built in?